# Command Line Column in Task Manager

Tags: windows-server-2012, task-manager, command-line-arguments

I try to detect what one of many similar by name tasks gets very high memory use.
I add to view column "Command line" in Task Manager, but this column is blank for these tasks.

How can I get command line params for these tasks?

Thank you.

Comment: You may be interested in the image name column instead or use a program like Process Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Also I'm interesting in command line parameters, with whih task starts. As I understand, the "Image name path" column is path to exe file.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the processes? Maybe a screenshot? In all the Task Manager instances I've tried (2012, 2012 R2, 10), the only processes with a blank in the `Command line` column were a few low-level System processes.

Comment: There are standard background processes by IBM Integration Bus 10 - DataFlowEngine.exe
Sorry, I can't make screenshot - it's restricted area ;(